# is Python 2 necessary to run npm zip? I want to zip a theme consisting .hbs files. I'm getting the following error while running npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install, ghost-blog

command npm install exits with the following error code. The last lines are redundant and I have escaped those lines.

```
   8730 error npm ERR! code 1
8730 error npm ERR! path C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloner8L4oe\node_modules\node-sass
8730 error npm ERR! command failed
8730 error npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
8730 error npm ERR! Building: E:\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloner8L4oe\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
8730 error npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'E:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\xyz\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_cacache\\tmp\\git-cloner8L4oe\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
8730 error npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
8730 error npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.4 | win32 | x64
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
8730 error npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```